# Apply gradient to sphere object with JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, gradient, radial-gradients, javafx-3d

I'm working in JavaFX for a class, and I'm trying to apply a gradient to a sphere, but (obviously), I can't figure out how to do it. I'm stuck because I know that a sphere is an object, and so it needs to have a material, but (as far as colors go), a PhongMaterial only takes one color, and so it won't take a gradient because a gradient is a range of colors. So basically what I'm trying to is the following:

```
    Sphere sphere = new Sphere(50);
    RadialGradient rg = new RadialGradient(0, 0, 0, 0, 5, true, CycleMethod.REPEAT, /*arbitrary/irrelevant color Stop objects*/));
    PhongMaterial pm = new PhongMaterial();
    pm.setDiffuseMap(pm);
    sphere.setMaterial(asdf);
```

Now obviously this code doesn't work, but I guess it's the idea/flow of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right about one thing, `PhongMaterial` takes a `Color` as diffuse color, and that doesn't allow a `Gradient`. For that, it should accept `Paint`, but that is not the case.

So we have to look for different alternatives.

**DiffuseMap**

If you check `PhongMaterial`, you can set the [diffuse map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/PhongMaterial.html#diffuseMapProperty) with an image. That means that you can use an existing image with some gradient and apply it to the sphere.

Something like this:

```
Sphere sphere = new Sphere(100);
PhongMaterial material = new PhongMaterial();
material.setDiffuseMap(new Image("http://westciv.com/images/wdblogs/radialgradients/simpleclorstops.png"));
sphere.setMaterial(material);
```

will produce the following result:

[image]

**Dynamic DiffuseMap**

Obviously, this has the disadvantage of depending on a static image. What if you want to modify that dynamically?

You can do that, if you generate your radial gradient, render it on a secondary scene and take a snapshot of it. This snapshot returns a `WritableImage` that you can use directly as diffuse map.

Something like this:

```
Scene aux = new Scene(new StackPane(), 100, 100, 
        new RadialGradient(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, true, CycleMethod.REPEAT, 
                new Stop(0, Color.GREEN), new Stop(0.4, Color.YELLOW), 
                new Stop(0.6, Color.BLUE), new Stop(0.7, Color.RED)));
WritableImage snapshot = aux.snapshot(null);

Sphere sphere = new Sphere(100);
PhongMaterial material = new PhongMaterial();
material.setDiffuseMap(snapshot);
sphere.setMaterial(material);
```

You will have now:

[image]

**Density Map**

There is still another option to use a mathematical function to generate a density map, and the colors will be given by a mapping to that function.

For that you can't use the built-in `Sphere`, but you have to either create your own `TriangleMesh` and play with the texture coordinates, or you can simply use FXyz, an open source JavaFX 3D [library](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz) with a number of different primitives and texture options.

For this case, you can get the library from Maven Central (`org.fxyz3d:fxyz3d:0.3.0`), use a `SegmentedSphereMesh` control, and then select the texture mode `Vertices3D:

```
SegmentedSphereMesh sphere = new SegmentedSphereMesh(100);
sphere.setTextureModeVertices3D(1530, p -> p.z);
```

Note the function in this case is just based on the `z` coordinate, but obviously you can modify that as needed.

[image]

Check the library (there is a sampler), to explore other options.